# How to programmatically add attributes to objects?

Tags: ruby, openstruct

I have an array of hashes, which I would rather be turned into an array of objects with attributes programmatically added to those objects.

I'm try this at the moment

```
obj = OpenStruct.new

resulthash["users"].collect { |u|
  u.each do |k,v|
    obj.send("#{k}=#{v}");
  end
}
```

To recap I'm trying to do

```
obj.foo = "bar"
obj.hello = "world"
```

But programmatically if for example to the array/hash looked liked this

```
{"users"=>[{"foo"=>"bar","hello"=>"world"}]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object#send` takes a method name as the first argument and optionally arguments to pass to the method as the remaining arguments.

Thus, `obj.send("#{k}=#{v}")` really tries to call methods named something like `"foo=bar"`, which is not the same as calling `foo=` with an argument `"bar"`.

So for one, the right way would be

```
resulthash["users"].each { |u|
  u.each do |k,v|
    obj.send("#{k}=", v)
  end
}
```

Note that I am using `#each` and not `#collect` because we do not want to transform the Hash.

Also, if your example reflects your final goal of just converting an array of Hashes into a single OpenStruct, you can just combine all Hashes into one and pass that to `OpenStruct.new`:

```
h = resulthash["users"].inject({}) { |acc, v| acc.merge(v) }
obj = OpenStruct.new(h)
```

Comment: that helped a lot, the end I looped through the array, create a new OpenStruct and added it to an array.